# Fade soft body modifier off an object slowly?

Tags: animation, modifiers, shape-keys, soft-body

I am nearing the end of a project, but I have run into a hurdle that I have been trying to solve for ages (sweating face emoji)

In the video a dragon has had a spell cast onto it making its body into a floppy 'soft body modified mess'

What I now need to do is fade this effect out, as by this point it has been healed.

It will be in free fall this whole time. Ideally it will just be a shape key or something like that I can insert keyframes for...  going from 1 soft body full affect to 0 soft body no effect.

I have tried using drivers and shape keys but nothing is really working and it is a bit beyond me I think.

reference: [image: Dragon post spell, pre healing]

Thanks!

Comment: maybe baking your animation and applying the softbody as shapekey on a duplicate will help

Comment: this is just off the top of my head: If you use animation nodes, you can recreate a mesh respecting its modifiers. So if you average out the position of each corresponding vertex [pos_with_SB * f + pos_without_SB * (1-f)] where f(actor) ranges from 0-1. Don't quote me on the math here...